# For which values of $a_{ij}$, $\langle u,v\rangle = a_{11}x_1y_1+a_{12}x_1y_2+a_{21}x_2y_1+a_{22}x_2y_2$ is an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $u = (x_1,x_2)$ and $v=(y_1,y_2)$

Then, when:

$\langle u,v\rangle = a_{11}x_1y_1+a_{12}x_1y_2+a_{21}x_2y_1+a_{22}x_2y_2$
is an inner product?

The exercise asks me first to prove that the additive and multiplicative conditions of the inner product definition are satisfied. I did this.
Then, it asks me to prove that the third condition (commutativity) is satisfied only when $M$ is symetric, where $M$ is the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}& a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$

So by the commutative property of an inner product we should have:

$$\langle u,v\rangle = \langle v,u\rangle \implies \\a_{11}x_1y_1+a_{12}x_1y_2+a_{21}x_2y_1+a_{22}x_2y_2 =  a_{11}y_1x_1+a_{12}y_1x_2+a_{21}y_2x_1+a_{22}y_2x_2$$

How to conclude that $M$ is symetric from the equations above?

The last thing the exercise asks me to do is to find which matrices define inner products in $\mathbb R^2$ according to the given definition:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

The answer for this item is only $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

but the exercise says that the third definition is satisfied when $M$ is symetric, but $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$, but why isn't this one an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetry: You have concluded that two polynomial expressions in $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ must be the equal for all values of the variables. This is true if and only if the coefficients of like terms are the same on both sides of the equals sign.

The last matrix $[^{1\;1}_{1\;1}]$ does not define an inner product because $\langle(1,-1),(1,-1)\rangle=0$ but $(1,-1)$ is not the zero vector. It seems you have forgotten to check positivity.

Comment: But $a_11x_1y_1 = a_11y_1x_1$ doesn't conclude anything! Could you explain me this part better?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: No, that particular term doesn't conclude anything. But there are other terms.